# What is Android wakelock UPDATE_BITMAP?

Tags: wakelock

On my phone, the biggest wakelock offender is "Android System" wakelock UPDATE_BITMAP. It is held for about 30 minutes per day.

Any idea what that may be? I do not use any background.

Comment: Do you use a live/moving wallpaper app or some kind of wallpaper changer app?

Comment: I do not use wallpaper at all. I change wallpaper on lockscreen programatically, but it takes fraction of second. It looks like applications may draw even when the phone is locked and screen off...